# Show that there exists open sets $P$ and $Q$ in $X$ such that $p \in P, S \subseteq Q$, and $P\cap Q = \emptyset$ in the metric space $(X,d)$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $S\subseteq X$ is finite, and $p \in X$, but $p \notin S$.
> Show that there exists open sets $P$ and $Q$ in $X$ such that $p \in P, S \subseteq Q$, and $P \cap Q = \emptyset$.

---

**Attempt:**
Let $S=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\}$ and $m=\min\{d(p,s_i):i=1,2,\ldots,n\}>0$.

I claimed that if $P=B_r(p)$ and $Q=\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_r(s_i)$ with
$r=\frac{m}{2}>0$, then $p \in P, S \subseteq Q$, and $P\cap Q=\emptyset$.

To this end, let $P=B_r(p)$ and $Q=\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_r(s_i)$.
Notice by definition that
$$B_r(p)=\{q \in X: d(p,q)<r\}$$
and
$$B_r(s_i)=\{t \in X: d(s_i,t)<r\},$$
for any $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
Now, both $P$ and $Q$ are open sets.

Clearly, $\boxed{p \in B_r(p)=P}$ and for any $s_i \in S$, we have $s_i \in B_r(s_i)$. It follows that $s_i \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_r(s_i)=Q$. It follows that $\boxed{S \subseteq Q}$.

Now, it suffices to show that $P \cap Q=\emptyset$. Suppose for contradiction that $P \cap Q \neq \emptyset$. Then, there exists $u \in X$ such that
$$u \in B_r(p) \cap B_r(s_i),$$ for some $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
It means that $d(p,u)<r=\frac{m}{2}$ and $d(u,s_i)<r=\frac{m}{2}$.
Notice that
$$m \le d(p,s_i) \le d(p,u) + d(u,s_i) < \frac{m}{2}+\frac{m}{2}=m,$$
which gives $m<m$, a contradiction. Thus, $\boxed{P \cap Q = \emptyset}$.

Therefore, we found two open sets $P$ and $Q$ in $X$ such that $p \in P, S \subseteq Q$, and $P \cap Q = \emptyset$, as desired. Q.E.D.

Does this approach correct? Thanks in advanced for any comments and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems to be correct but you may reduce the length (to make it concise etc) by using the fact that all metric spaces are also $T_2$ space (Hausdorff space) and the result follows from the definition of hausdorff space.

Comment: But, is it correct?

Comment: @gerrr yes your approach seems correct to me